# Ruby equivalent of C# Linq Aggregate method

Tags: c#, ruby, linq, jruby, aggregate

Whats the ruby equivalent of Linq Aggregate method. It works something like this

```
  var factorial = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Aggregate((acc, i) => acc * i);
```

the variable acc is getting accumulated every time the value from the array sequence is passed to the lambda..

Comment: It's called `reduce` -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29 for the equivalent in various languages.

Comment: You should probably make this comment an answer so Ramesh can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is usually called a *fold* in mathematics as well as pretty much any programming language. It's an instance of the more general concept of a *catamorphism*. Ruby inherits its name for this feature from Smalltalk, where it is called `inject:into:` (used like `aCollection inject: aStartValue into: aBlock.`) So, in Ruby, it is called `inject`. It is also aliased to `reduce`, which is somewhat unfortunate, since that usually means something slightly different.

Your C# example would look something like this in Ruby:

```
factorial = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(:*)
```

Although one of these would probably be more idiomatic:

```
factorial = (1..5).reduce(:*)
factorial = 1.upto(5).reduce(:*)
```

Comment: I love `Symbol#to_proc` for arithmetic!

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Actually, this isn't `Symbol#to_proc` (note the missing ampersand). `Enumerable#inject` has an "overload" that takes a symbol for the folding operation. This won't work with `Enumerable#collect`, for example.

Comment: +1 for using the word "catamorphism". I swear, every time I read one of your posts I have to look something up.

Comment: +1. But if you think "reduce" is unfortunate why use it in the answer? :-) inject is more used in the community (a search in my installed gems showed a 1910 vs 13). And it may be worth adding an example with the "expanded" usage: 1.upto(5).inject { |acc, x| acc * x }

Answer (score 2):

See [Enumerable#inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494).

Usage:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
factorial = a.inject(1) do |product, i|
  product * i
end
```

Comment: As @Gabe points out, it also has the alias `reduce`, and that's the mathematical term really.